# Sort on non visible table data

Tags: tablesorter

I have a table where one of the columns shows a "Last modified" time stamp. This time stamp is in human readable form e.g. "5 minutes ago" and not in a date time format. The problem is that this does not sort well, since obviously I want the table to sort from the absolute time stamp when I sort on that column.

Is there a way to force talbesorter to use a data tag attribute to sort on instead?
E.g. 5 minutes ago

Using motties tablesorter fork
http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#Support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the [`textAttribute` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#textattribute) to match the data-attribute being used as the time stamp. If the date format matches a parser then it will be detected automatically.

Alternatively, you could use the [sugar.js](http://sugarjs.com/dates) library to translate the human readable date into a date object - see [this demo](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-parsers-dates.html).

Comment: Just what I was looking for! Suspected that the option existed somewhere.